# ASP.NET MVC - Render section conditionally in Layout

Tags: asp.net, layout, conditional-statements, render

i have following code in my _Layout.cshtml:

```
@if (SiteConfig.Instance.HasCustomMarkup)
{
     @RenderSection("bodyPart1", false)
     @RenderBody()
     @RenderSection("bodyPart2", false)
}
else
{
    <div id="mainContainer">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>        
}
```

So i try to render sections only on some condition. But it is not work and i have an exception:

```
The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page ...
```

Is there any workaround in mvc for this purposes?
thanks!

Answer (score 26):

Simply check whether or not section exists, i.e.:

```
@if (IsSectionDefined("bodyPart1"))
{
    @RenderSection("bodyPart1")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response! It is always defined i my case. But i found the solution that works - wrap section definition into <text></text> tags, then define sections if some condition true at run-time, and this way i haven't get exception.

Comment: @igorGIS please post your answer :)

Comment: This is actually the opposite of what's happening to the OP. The above code (now obsolete with an override to rendersecction) will prevent an error if you try to render a section which doesn't exist in the child page.

The OP's error occurs when you HAVE section on a child page, but without a RenderSection method on the parent

Answer (score 3):

To prevent the exception `The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered...` you can just emulate rendering call without actual rendering.

```
@if (SOME_CONDITION)
{
    @RenderSection("SectionName", false)
}
else
{
    var fakeSectionRender = RenderSection("SectionName", false);
    if (fakeSectionRender != null) {
        fakeSectionRender.WriteTo(TextWriter.Null);
    }
}
```

The downside to consider is performance, because this approach forces rendering even when it is not needed.

Comment: Note that in Visual Studio, if you're using BrowserLink, this will cause an error saying the "SectionName" has already been rendered. Odd error, and difficult to track down. This solution works well otherwise.